# updating mysql using JOptionPane

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, joptionpane

I am trying to update my mysql table using JoptionPane. So the idea is to as for the id to update first then check if it exit then, ask for new value to replace it with.

here is the source for the line

```
else if(ae.getSource()==updateVid){
        String id =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ID you want to update:");


        try {
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","success123");
            stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            int numRows = stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE FROM films WHERE id='"+id+"'");

            String ids =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ID:");
            String fn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Title:");
            String sn =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Description:");
            String tn =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Year:");
            String frn =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Art:");
            String fifn =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Duration:");



            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM films");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Video has been Rented to the Out","New Rent" ,JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            while (rs.next()) {


            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: so whats wrong with this code?

Comment: Nothing i just needs the line of code to execute multiple update by asking the user to input the id first

Comment: put the whole block in while loop..

Answer (score 1):

Use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` as your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

I think this is what you need :

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE films set title = ?,description=?,year=?,art=?,duration=? where id=?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);

String fn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Title:");
String sn =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Description:");
String tn =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Year:");
String frn =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Art:");
String fifn =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Duration:");

ps.setString(1,fn);
ps.setString(2,sn);
ps.setString(3,tn);
ps.setString(4,frn);
ps.setString(5,fifn);
ps.setString(6,id);
int numRows = ps.executeUpdate();
```